# How to add a node to a child object

Tags: javascript

I want to insert an object say-`{id:parentid+appendvalue}` in each of children array using javascript/jquery. Here is my sample data:

```
var obj={
    "name": "root",
    "id":12,
    "children": [
        {
            "name": "child-1",
            "children": [
                {
                    "name": "inner-child"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "child-2"
        }
    ]
};
```

Each object is of the format `{name,id,children[]}`.Here , I want to insert `{id:parentid+".0"}` recursively to all children nodes so that , I would get the following output.

```
var obj={
    "name": "root",
    **"id":12**,
    "children": [
        {
            "name": "child-1",
             **"id": 12.0**

            "children": [
                {
                    "name": "inner-child",
                     **"id" : 12.0.0**
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "child-2",
            **"id": 12.1**
        }
    ]
};
```

Please note the children object is **not** restricted to any level. Please help.

Comment: @sureshjain: The question doesn't relate to JSON. JSON is a textual notation used for data interchange. Your question is about modifying JavaScript objects in memory, which is unrelated to JSON.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
for(var i = 0; i < obj.children.length; i++)
{
    var parentIDString = parentid + ".0";
    for(var j = 0; j < i; j++)
    {
        parentIDString += ".0";
    }    
    obj.children[i]['id'] = parentIDString;

}
```

Comment: Hi brso05, I need to append ".0" based on the level of children.say , first children node will have id:12.0 , second level children node will have id:12.0.0. this has to be done recursively ,keeping in track the level of children from the parent node.

Comment: You can use a loop and create a string appending the number of 0's needed depending on how many children there are so far...I'll post an example.

Comment: @sureshjain I'm not sure exactly what you want but maybe my updated answer will help you?

Comment: in my sample JSON data, I want to insert JSON object {"id":"value"}. in each of my children object array such that the value for id should be - parentid(provided in sample json)+".0" . the value ".0" should be appended the times equal to the level of child.

Comment: the output should be like this- {
    "name": "root",
    **"id":12**,
    "children": [
        {
            "name": "child-1",
             **"id": 12.0**

            "children": [
                {
                    "name": "inner-child-1",
                     **"id" : 12.0.0**
                },{
                    "name": "inner-child-2",
                     **"id" : 12.0.1**
                } ]}